# Why Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing not working properly while using extended store?

Tags: extjs, store, extjs4.1, extend

I'm facing an issue using `Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing` inside an ExtJS 4.1.1 MVC application. As far as I know, I have to provide my own `Ext.data.Store` extension for use inside an Ext MVC architecture, but doing this, form fields displayed inside the editing ruler remain empty, even though the corresponding record is fully filled. Indeed, before installing the plugin in my MVC project, I made a quick test in which the store is instanciated from the core class and everything works correctly.

I have googled a bit about that and found some quite close topics, but nothing that could help me so far. So, I hope anyone here has encountered the same problem.

### Update

I have tried to reproduce this bug here http://jsfiddle.net/hcNgP/ with no success. I currently suspect my version of ExtJS (`Ext.getVersion()` gives me 4.1.1.1). I'll go back here with more details as soon as possible. Thanks everyone.

Comment: A working demo, ideally in a jsFiddle, would greatly help corner this particular issue.

Comment: As I said to @dbrin, this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcNgP/) works correctly. It seems that my problem doesn't directly rely on the implementation of the MVC architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by extended `store`, but here is a full example that works as designed. 
http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/uu56M/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By "extended store" I mean defining a new class that extends `Ext.data.Store`. Sorry, my english is not so good :) Could you tell me how I'm supposed to say it? So, for some reasons (keep code consistent, avoid loosing MVC features like accessors, etc...), I'd like to keep doing things as I do. From this point of view, I'm rather looking for a patch.

Comment: I have made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcNgP/) based on yours. The store extends `Ext.data.Store` but this time everything works as expected... That doesn't really help me indeed...

Comment: You need to demonstrate the problem. I have no idea what is not working in your example. I cannot help you without seeing any code.

Comment: Of course, I don't expect that you guess the problem :) I just wanted to answer to somebody who wanted a jsFiddle, but I realized that I wasn't able to reproduce the bug. I have checked my project's code again but I haven't found anything weird. I suspect my version of ExtJS to be guilty. Indeed, your jsFiddle loads version 4.1.1 and I'm working with version 4.1.1.1 (`Ext.getVersion()` told me so)... Unfortunately, I have no more time to investigate deeper for now. Anyway, thank you for having spent some time trying to help me. If I find something interesting about this bug I'll tell you.